# phpunit phar has long delay when executing

Tags: php, phpunit, phar

I have the latest PHPUnit as a phar, placed in /usr/local/bin/phpunit (4.1.3).  When I execute this file on my vagrant host (ubuntu 12.04, php 5.3.10), it takes what seems to be 30s to 60s before it actually starts performing the unit tests.  I cannot figure out why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to close this for now as I believe the primary issue is that I am working with a shared folder, and I cannot update to 5.5 like monte suggested.  I appreciate your response!  I will just have to deal with it for now.  If I get a moment I will try a vagrant with 5.5 and OpCode like you suggested, and just run phpunit to see if it is faster, even in a shared folder.  If so, I will change my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when running phars in production (AWS's phar.  Unfortunately, PHP doesn't do any caching around phar archives, even when using APC as an OpCode cache.  So, on each request, PHP is unarchiving and parsing the entire phar.  My workaround has been to avoid phars in production unless the archive is small.

If you have the option to upgrade PHP 5.5 w/ OpCode caching, you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I believe this may actually be due to using phpunit on a shared folder (I have Ubuntu 14.04 host, but our servers are 12.04, so I have vagrant vms).  I use VirtualBox for my virtualization.

Comment: I can't upgrade to 5.5 right now, as our apps are not suited for anything above 5.3.10